# Proposed WCF Model is this Possible?

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server

I am new to WCF. Is the below proposed WCF model possible?

There are to components to it.

1. Save the files
2. Convert the files

I can use multiple instances of WCF in part one but I am restricted to use one instance in part two of WCF.

**Is this model possible. If yes, How can I make part of WCF as**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single]
```

and for part two

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Multiple]
```

Please help me with some technical details.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: why is the conversion service a service and not a worker that just processes work when available?

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain difference b/w service and worker?

Comment: the service is exposed to the outside world and can be called the worker is just a thread or windows service on the machine not exposed.

Comment: Yes, right i can use that as a worker as i do not need to expose this functionality.

Comment: who will run this worker process or worker function?